# How to style Android MaterialCalendars various components

Tags: android, android-styles, android-datepicker, material-components-android

I'm attempting to style this `MaterialCalendar`, but I'm not getting anywhere with it, any help would be appreciated.
My `styles.xml` looks similar to the below:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
    <item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/ThemeMaterialCalendar</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeMaterialCalendar" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/AlterDialogButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/AlterDialogButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/ThemeMaterialCalendarTextButton</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeMaterialCalendarTextButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton.Dialog.Flush">
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AlterDialogButtonStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Which renders something like:

[image]

The very light blue/cyan is my `colorAccent` the header is the purple-y colour. Those are just fine. I was able to change them with the above `styles.xml`.

However I want to also change the dark grey background of the `MaterialCalendar` to white, and then of course change the text from white to black or grey (so it can be seen), as well as make the arrows for month and year selection. Any selected year or day should be highlighted with the accent color.

Essentially I want something similar to this (please ignore the fact that the below screen shot is of the old `DatePickerDialog` and not the new `MaterialCalendar`):

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I don't want to change any of my primary, secondary or accent colours for the entire app (as it will ruin the rest of the colour scheme)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to customize the colors in the `MaterialDatePicker` is to override them:

```
<style name="MaterialCalendarThemeBackground" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/....</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/....</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/....</item>      
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

and then use:

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
builder.setTheme(R.style.MaterialCalendarThemeBackground);
```

The **background color** of the `MaterialDatePicker` is based on **`colorSurface`** attribute.

```
<style name="MaterialCalendarThemeBackground" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Instead if you want to change the other colors using a custom style you can do:

- **Day**: it is based on `colorOnSurface`. You can define:

```
    <style name="MaterialCalendarThemeBackground" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/CustomMaterialCalendar</item>
    </style>
```

with:

```
<style name="CustomMaterialCalendar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
    <item name="dayStyle">@style/CustomWidget_Day</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomWidget_Day" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day">
    <item name="itemTextColor">@color/...</item>
    <item name="itemStrokeColor">@color/....</item>
</style>
```

- **SelectedDay**: it is based on `colorPrimary`/`colorOnPrimary`. You can define:

```
    <style name="CustomMaterialCalendar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
       <item name="daySelectedStyle">@style/CustomSelected</item>
    </style>
```

with:

```
  <style name= "CustomSelected" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day.Selected">
    <item name="itemFillColor">...</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">...</item>
  </style>
```

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on **@Gabriele Mariotti** answer for those in the future that want to customize the MaterialDatePicker more.

(Side note) : I noticed the MaterialDatePicker on tablets reverts to the default colors, I don't why that is so.

MaterialDatePicker size can be changed from full screen to dialog size through using this line

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
```

Set the theme of MaterialDatePicker:

```
builder.setTheme(R.style.CustomThemeOverlay_MaterialCalendar_Fullscreen);
```

I would recommend playing around with the styles and make changes to the colors to see what it actually changes if you are unsure.

```
<style name="AppTheme"  parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
   <item name="materialCalendarFullscreenTheme">@styleCustomThemeOverlay_MaterialCalendar_Fullscreen</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomThemeOverlay_MaterialCalendar_Fullscreen" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="materialCalendarStyle">@style/Custom_MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarHeaderTitle">@style/customHeaderTitle</item>
        <item name="materialCalendarHeaderSelection">@style/CustomHeaderSelection</item>
        <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/Buttons</item>
        <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/Buttons</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/...</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/...</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/...</item>
        <item name="colorOnSurface">@color/...</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/...</item>
    </style>


    <style name="Custom_MaterialCalendar.Fullscreen" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
        <item name="rangeFillColor">@color/...</item>
        <item name="dayStyle">@style/CustomWidget_Day</item>
        <item name="daySelectedStyle">@style/CustomSelected</item>
    </style>
    <style name="customHeaderTitle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderTitle">
        <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/...</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/...</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomHeaderSelection" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.HeaderSelection">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/...</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomWidget_Day" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="itemTextColor">@color/...</item>
    </style>
    <style name= "CustomSelected" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar.Day.Selected">
        <item name="itemFillColor">@color/...</item>
        <item name="itemStrokeColor">@color/...</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Buttons" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/...</item>
    </style>
```

I was able to make [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si4Uv.png) using this code: